# Get language name from locale string using .NET? ex: en_us => english

Tags: c#, .net, locale, cultureinfo

How can i find the language for a given locale?

Example: input: en_US
output: English

Using the .NET libraries? I tried the CultureInfo class, but i can't find something usefull.

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe?  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do not use the constructor of `CultureInfo`. It is faster to use the static `GetCultureInfo` method since this method is cached and returns an immutable (readonly) `CultureInfo` object.

According to the [Facebook SDK documentation concerning localization](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/), it is safe to assume that you can replace the underscore by a dash in order to allow .NET to understand the locale.

> Facebook locales follow ISO language
>   and country codes respectively,
>   concatenated by an underscore.
>
> The basic format is ''ll_CC'', where
>   ''ll'' is a two-letter language code,
>   and ''CC'' is a two-letter country
>   code. For instance, 'en_US' represents
>   US English.

Depending if you need the name to appear in english regardless of the language of the OS, use

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").EnglishName
```

If you need the name in the language of the OS, use:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks. But notice that like @ChrisSnowden said, this works only with en-US. Not with en_US.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use en-US not en_US with code like:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
string name = culture.DisplayName;
```

output: English (United States)

Comment: Should i use the replace method? "_" => "-" 
Because I get the locale string from facebook..

Comment: Yes, that would be the best approach to format the locale string into the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").EnglishName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
Dim culture1 As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim t As Thread = Thread.CurrentThread
Dim currentCulture As CultureInfo = t.CurrentCulture
Dim currentUICulture As CultureInfo = t.CurrentUICulture

'*** display cultures in console
Console.WriteLine("Current Culture: " & currentCulture.Name)
Console.WriteLine("Current UI Culture: " & currentUICulture.Name)
```