# C# getCultures in local/currentCulture

Tags: c#, asp.net, currentculture

The following code returns English names despite I localized the currentculture.

```
List<string> languageList = new List<string>();
CultureInfo[] cultureList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultureList)
    {
        languageList.Add(culture.DisplayName);
    }
```

What if I want the display names say in Italian, or in German or whatever language I specify? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `NativeName` property

Look at this question also [How to translate CultureInfo language names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names)

Comment: :S NativeName is not what I was looking for, I want all the languages in the language that I specify. But apparently, as your link notes, it is not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.displayname.aspx) property returns the culture name *in the language of the localized version of the .NET Framework*:

> This property represents the localized
>   name from the .NET Framework version.
>   For example, if the .NET Framework
>   English version is installed, the
>   property returns "English (United
>   States)" for the `en-US` culture name.
>   If the .NET Framework Spanish version
>   is installed, regardless of the
>   language that the system is set to
>   display, the culture name is displayed
>   in Spanish and the property for `en-US`
>   returns "Ingles (Estados Unidos)".

Use the [NativeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.nativename.aspx) property instead. However, note that you cannot obtain a culture name in a language different than its own (except, of course, English and the language of your version of the .NET Framework).