# Retrieve localized language names by CultureInfo

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to retrieve a localized language name from a given `CultureInfo`?

For instance i want to retrieve the german word for the spanish language?

*`CultureInfo` stores language names in english and the culture itself.*

I want to avoid storing translations of the language name itself in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. `CultureInfo` holds the native name for a language it represents (e.g. `fr-Ca` is `Francais Canadienne`), but `CultureInfo("fr-CA")` would not be aware that "German" in French is "Allemagne"

As indicated in this thread, you might be interested in the Google Translate APi:

ref: [How to translate CultureInfo language names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names)

Answer (score 0):

Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to select different language