# Get the display name of a culture name in localized culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am developing a multilanguage asp.net MVC application. In a grid, I am trying to display a list of cultures. These data must be displayed in the user language (current thread language).

For example, I get a list of languages codes :

```
fr-fr
en-gb
fr-ca
```

And I am doing this :

```
var cultureOne = new CultureInfo("fr-fr").DisplayName
var cultureTwo = new CultureInfo("en-gb").DisplayName
var cultureThird = new CultureInfo("fr-ca").DisplayName
```

The problem with that the code, is that the display name property is not localized (it's not depending on the user culture) but depending on the server culture I guess.

So as my machine is in french, I am always getting the same result (whether I am in English, french, Italian ...) :

```
français (France)
Anglais (Royaume-Uni)
français (Canada)
```

My goal is to obtain the following result :

- If I am in french :

  ```
  français (France)
  Anglais (Royaume-Uni)
  français (Canada)
  ```
- If I am in English:

  ```
  french (France)
  English (United Kingdom)
  french (Canada)
  ```
- If I am in italian:

  ```
  francese (Francia)
  inglese (Regno Unito)
  francese(Canada)
  ```

Comment: How about setting Application.CurrentCulture to english ? Or Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture also to english ?

Comment: This is already done when i swith my current language. For example, If I switch into italien, I am doing this Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("it-it")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names

Answer (score 0):

That one what I mean, DisplayName depends on this culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NativeName instead of DisplayName.

Comment: Native name provides only one localization - language's own translation, independent of user culture.