# After set CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture CultureInfo.DisplayName always returns english

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

After set `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` `CultureInfo.DisplayName` always returns english.

I try

```
    CultureInfo cu = new CultureInfo("ja-JP");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cu;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cu;
      // CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cu;
    // SetDefaultCulture(cu);
    Dictionary<string, string> ifile = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"([\w+\s*\.*]+\))");
    foreach (var item in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.FrameworkCultures))
    {

      I18nCulture country = new I18nCulture();
      var match = regex.Match(item.DisplayName);
      string countryName = match.Value.Length == 0 ? item.EnglishName : match.Value.Substring(0, match.Value.Length - 1);
      if (item.Name != "")
      { 
        ifile.Add(item.Name, item.DisplayName);
      }
    }

    string fn = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, "lib", "i18n", "culture", lng + ".json");
    Console.WriteLine("save : " + fn);
    saveObjectToJSON(ifile, fn);
```

When I run this code `item.DisplayName` is in german language, which is my current os system language. When I uncomment `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cu;` `item.DisplayName` is in english language. At this point I would expect `ja-JP` version of Display name.

How to get the culture display name in thread' s current culture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate CultureInfo language names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install [Japanese .NET Framework Language Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=30667).