# C# CultureInfo in currently selected language

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I know how to get the native name..

[image]

And if I change the website profile language to say fr-FR

[image]

The "All Languages" translates (Toutes les langues) and everything stays in "NativeName"

What I would like to do, is for example, if English (en-US) is selected (for the Website language, not the dropdown):

- English
- French
- German
- Spanish

and if Spanish is selected (for the Website language, not the dropdown)

- Inglés
- Francés
- Alemán
- Español

and of course if there are 2 Spanish ones (es-MX, es-ES)

- Español (MX)
- Español (ES)

(or whatever the default translated language might be)

[image: Watch]

Note how the current thread is ja-JP and the CultureInfo has ja-JP for the US English CultureInfo (en-US), but I would expect DisplayName to actually use the locale / current thread setting to get that information.... without having to install language packs that is.

And for PMF who wanted the code sample, it is just a Dictionary<string, string> of Culture.Name and Culture.NativeName and in the dropdown it just uses the KVP for key and value.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code that generates this list? Not everyone might directly know that.

Comment: CultureInfos have various names associated with them for different purposes: `IetfLanguageTag`, `DisplayName`, `NativeName`, `EnglishName`, etc. But they can't possibly be expected to have the language's name in every other language--that would imply that every time a culture is added, every other culture needs to be updated to know what it's called in that language, violating the Open/Closed Principle. You are going to need to create your own resource mapping for all of the languages that you want to support.

Comment: it is good that the displayed language is i the native language of the country, when i get an Spanish ui and want to change it to German, i can find it without knowing the language at all, your system for example for Chinese would imply to change it i must at least be able to read Chinese.

Comment: >> But they can't possibly be expected to have the language's name in every other language--<< Of course not. The idea would be that if Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and/or Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is something like es-ES, then there should be some setting (DisplayName?). based on the current culture. Not that everything stores names for everything else.

Comment: NBK: The idea is that I would build a string for the web display. If you are in Spanish you would see Ingles [English]) and if you were in English you might see Spanish (Espanol)... so I don't need "advice" as to what you think is best versus what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Apparently, it does not seem that this is possible; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432813/how-to-translate-cultureinfo-language-names

Comment: it is not possible from .NET natively, you probably need an external API like google translate API to do this 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-csharp#0